# A question about divisions of integral polynomials modulo power of primes.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I am having a hard time understanding a simple theorem in Hardy's "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers":

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be integral polynomials. If $p$ is a prime and $f(x)g(x)\equiv 0 \pmod {p^a}$ and $f(x) \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, then $g(x)\equiv 0 \pmod {p^a}$.

The proof is very simple when $a=1$. The proof in the book proceeds by forming "$f_1(x)$ from $f(x)$ by rejecting all terms of $f(x)$ whose coefficients are divisible by $p$, and $g_1(x)$ similarly. If $f(x)\not\equiv 0$ and $g(x)\not\equiv 0$, then the first coefficient in $f_1(x)$ and $g_1(x)$ are not divisible by $p$, and therefore the first coefficient in $f_1(x)g_1(x)$ is not divisible by $p$. Therefore, $f(x)g(x) \equiv f_1(x)g_1(x) \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$."

The problem is the author then says by rejecting multiples of $p^a$ from $g(x)$ instead, we get the general result in the same way. This is where I do not understand the proof.

In the case of $a=1$, the whole question is essentially in modulo $p$, so one can reject the coefficients divisible by $p$. However, in the general case, I think one cannot reject multiples of $p$ from $f(x)$ because the resulting equation should be in modulo $p^a$.

For example, let $c_0$ be the first coefficient in $f(x)$ not divisible by $p$, and $d_0$ be the first coefficient in $g(x)$ not divisible by $p^a$. Then $c_0d_0$ is indeed not divisible by $p^a$. But the coefficients of $f(x)$ in front of $c_0$ and those of $g(x)$ behind $d_0$ can contribute to the total sum of the coefficient of the corresponding degree. Say, $p=3$, $a=2$, $f(x)=3x^2 + x$, $g(x)=6x + 1$, then $f(x) \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, $g(x) \not \equiv 0 \pmod {p^a}$, $c_0=1$, $d_0=6$ but the coefficient of $x^2$ is $9$, so the same proof strategy does not work anymore although $f(x)g(x) \not\equiv 0 \pmod {p^a}$ indeed.

My question is then, what I should add in order to amend the proof? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Work inductively, note that coefficients of $g$ are divisible by $p^{a-1}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you elaborate more on the argument? For one thing, I cannot see why $g$ is divisible by $p^{a-1}$.

Comment: The "similar way" Hardy was referring to was not "the leading coefficient in the product will be non-zero" but "some coefficient in the product will be non-zero".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could you give some hint to the problem? I think I have thought about this too much and I cannot approach this problem with simple mind anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the question from not being answered and to help those who might have stumbled on the problem, here is the solution:

Use induction on $a$. $a=1$ has been already provided. Now suppose $g\equiv 0 \pmod {p^a}$, then one can see the same argument I used to provide a fallacy in the original proof does not work anymore, hence $g\equiv 0 \pmod {p^{a+1}}$.